# How to read JSON string [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Ajax call

```
 $( "#day").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(request) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/url.htm',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: '${someId}'
            }),
           dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.b === true) {
                    $("#fruit").val(response.a);
                }
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText);
        });
    }
    });
```

String response from `ajax` call is as below

```
{
  "a": "apple",
  "b": true
}
```

I have tried reading it using `var json = $.parseJSON(response);` and I get exception `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

`console.log(response);` shows data on console as

```
Object {
  "a": "apple",
  "b": true
}
```

I want to fetch value of "a" and "b". How can this be achieved?

Comment: there is no need to parse it again, use `response.a` and `response.b` to access value of a and b

Comment: `response` is not a string it seems. Do a `typeof response` and you will see that it is already an object created automatically from the json response.

Comment: Than it is not a string. You can access it's properties directly just like @PranavRam said. Or alternatively you can use the indexer operator like this: `response["a"]` and `response["b"]`.

Comment: share your code of ajax request ..........

Comment: set `dataType:'json'`

Comment: With JSON datatType, tried both forms: `console.log(response['d']);` and `console.log(response.d);`; Still gets undefined

Comment: then the problem will be in your requested url page

Comment: Found the problem - there were extra quotes;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already on JSON format. you don't need to parse it anymore.

use it like this.

```
  response.a;
  response.b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please review it I have done some changes :) if any query please ask me

```
$( "#day").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(request) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/url.htm',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: '${someId}'
                }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response['b'] === true) {
                        $("#fruit").val(response['a']);
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText);
            });
        }
        });
```

Comment: With JSON datatType, tried both forms: `console.log(response['d']);` and `console.log(response.d);`; Still gets undefined

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
var ajaxResult = '{"a":"apple","b": true}';

var json= $.parseJSON(ajaxResult );

console.log(json.a);
```